# Best way to do a fuzzy key lookup in Python?

Tags: python, data-structures, hashmap, hashtable, python-collections

I have a problem where I need to do a fuzzy lookup in a hash map, i.e. return the value corresponding to that key that most closely resembles the query, in my case measured by the Levenshtein distance.

My current approach is to subclass `dict` with a special lookup method that computes the Levenshtein distance against all keys, then returns the value of the key with the lowest score. Basically this:

```
import Levenshtein

class FuzzyLookupDict(dict):

    def fuzzy_lookup(self, query):
        levs = [(key, Levenshtein.ratio(query, key)) for key in self.keys()]
        key, score = max(levs, key=lambda lev: lev[1])
        return self.get(key)
```

Is this a good approach or is there a better solution that I haven't thought of?

Comment: Unless you can figure out a clever way to index your keys in an extra table, I don't think it is possible to do this without searching through all your keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is normally solved with [Levenshtein automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_automaton). A Levenshtein automaton for a string *w* and a number *n* is a finite state automaton that can recognize the set of all strings whose Levenshtein distance from *w* is at most *n*.

This algorithm is significantly faster than using dynamic programming to compute the Levenshtein distance separately for each dictionary word.

Jule Jacob's blog post [Levenshtein automata can be simple and fast](http://julesjacobs.github.io/2015/06/17/disqus-levenshtein-simple-and-fast.html) is a good starting point and Nick Johnsonz's [Damn Cool Algorithms: Levenshtein Automata](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Levenshtein-Automata) is a more in depth intro.

You can find some Python implementations on Github, for example https://github.com/antoinewdg/pyffs.